# Using anonymous functions with summarize_each or mutate_each

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use anonymous functions in calls to `summarize_each`:

```
# how to use an anonymous function in dplyr
df_foo = data_frame(x = rnorm(100),
                    y = rnorm(100))

df_foo %>% 
  summarize_each(funs(function(bar) sum(bar/10)))
```

How would I go about achieving this? Obviously, naming the function before using it works.

Comment: I don't see the need for that - why don't you just do `summarize_each(funs(sum(./10)))`? The `.` is already defined as the data/column so you don't need the extra `function(bar)` part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a matter of using a lot of parentheses so everything gets evaluated:

```
df_foo %>% 
  summarize_each(funs(((function(bar){sum(bar/10)})(.))))
#
# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#          x          y
#      (dbl)      (dbl)
# 1 1.113599 -0.4766853
```

where you need

- parentheses around the function definition so it gets defined,
- a set of parentheses with a `.` to tell `funs` which parameter to stick the data passed to it in (seemingly redundant with single-parameter functions, but not so with multi-parameter ones; see `?funs` for more examples), and
- parentheses around the whole thing to actually evaluate it,

which is kind of ridiculous, but that seems to be the most concise `funs` can handle. It makes some sense if you look at what you'd have to write to evaluate a similar anonymous function on its own line, e.g.

```
(function(bar){sum(bar/10)})(df_foo$x)
```

though the pair wrapping the whole thing are extra for `funs`. You can use braces `{}` instead for the outer pair if you prefer, which might make more syntactic sense.

Comment: This is a really complicated way of writing `df_foo %>% summarize_each(funs(sum(./10)))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus True. I assumed the actual function was more complicated, but just using `.` is a better way to go before resorting to the syntax above.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yeah, because what I really want to do is divide by 10.

Comment: This works nicely for instances where you need a function applied to every column, which needs to reference another column within the table.

funs((( function(x, pid) { n_distinct(ifelse(x, pid, NA), na.rm=TRUE) } )(., personid)))