# Using an anonymous function in mutate

Tags: r

I want to use the character strings from one column of a dataframe as the search string in a `sub` search of the character strings in another column of the dataframe on a row-by-row basis. I would like to do this using `dplyr::mutate`. I have figured out a way to do this using an anonymous function and `apply`, but I feel like `apply` shouldn't be necessary and I must be doing something wrong with how I'm implementing `mutate`. (And yes, I know that `tools::file_path_sans_ext` can give me the final result without needing to use mutate; I'm just want to understand how to use `mutate`.)

Here is the code that I think should work but doesn't:

```
files.vec <- dir(
    dir.target, 
    full.names = T, 
    recursive = T, 
    include.dirs = F, 
    no.. = T
)

library(tools)
files.paths.df <- as.data.frame(
    cbind(
        path = files.vec, 
        directory = dirname(files.vec), 
        file = basename(files.vec), 
        extension = file_ext(files.vec)
    )
)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
files.split.df <- files.paths.df %>% 
    mutate(
        no.ext = function(x) {
            sub(paste0(".", x["extension"], "$"), "", x["file"])
        }
    )
| Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
| Column `no.ext` is of unsupported type function
```

Here is the code that works, using `apply`:

```
files.split.df <- files.paths.df %>% 
    mutate(no.ext = apply(., 1, function(x) {
        sub(paste0(".", x["extension"], "$"), "", x["file"])
    }))
```

Can this be done without `apply`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently what you need is a whole bunch of parentheses. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36906989/3277050

In your situation it looks like:

```
files.split.df <- files.paths.df %>% 
  mutate(
    no.ext = (function(x) {sub(paste0(".", x["extension"], "$"), "", x["file"])})(.)
  )
```

So it seems like if you wrap the whole function definition in brackets you can then treat it like a regular function and supply arguments to it.

### New Answer

Really this is not the right way to use mutate at all though. I got focused in on the anonymous function part first without looking at what you are actually doing. What you need is a vectorized version of sub. So I used `str_replace` from the `stringr` package. Then you can just refer to columns by name because that is the beauty of dplyr:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

files.split.df <- files.paths.df %>% 
  mutate(
    no.ext = str_replace(file, paste0(".", extension, "$"), ""))
```

### Edit to Answer Comment

To use a user defined function where there isn't an existing vectorized function you could use `Vectorize` like this:

```
string_fun <- Vectorize(function(x, y) {sub(paste0(".", x, "$"), "", y)})
files.split.df <- files.paths.df %>% 
  mutate(
    no.ext = string_fun(extension, file))
```

Or if you really don't want to name the function, which I do not recommend as it is much harder to read:

```
files.split.df <- files.paths.df %>% 
  mutate(
    no.ext = (Vectorize(function(x, y) {sub(paste0(".", x, "$"), "", y)}))(extension, file))
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that post but couldn't follow what they were doing. I'll take a closer look and then accept your answer.

Comment: This solution works well. Thanks. In cases where there is not a pre-existing vectorized version of the function I want to use should I use `mapply`?